Vim Custom multiple custom syntax highlighting
function! CustomSyntax()
    syntax on
        
    syntax include @HTML syntax/html.vim
    syntax region htmlSnip matchgroup=SnipHTML start="html`" end="`" contains=@HTML
    
    syntax include @JSON syntax/json.vim
    syntax region jsonSnip matchgroup=SnipJSON start="json`" end="`" contains=@JSON
    
    syntax include @CPP syntax/cpp.vim
    syntax region cppSnip matchgroup=SnipCPP start="@begin=cpp@" end="@end=cpp@" contains=@CPP

endfunction

autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *  call CustomSyntax()

I would like to have multiple syntax regions in different languages. Right now only the first one is done. If I remove the first then the next is highlighted.
I was expecting all of the regions to be highlighted simultaneously

I'm not sure why this question was downvoted and got a close vote. It is well written, OP's goal is clear, the tags are relevant, there is sample code, and it is definitely a programming question. Sigh…

Syntax scripts generally have a guard in the form:
if exists("b:current_syntax")
    finish
endif

[...]

let b:current_syntax = "html"

which means in your case that:

the b:current_syntax variable is defined at the end of syntax/html.vim,
the syntax scripts that come after bail out because the variable is defined.

The solution to this problem is to nuke b:current_syntax after each syntax script is sourced:
function! CustomSyntax()
    syntax include @HTML syntax/html.vim
    unlet b:current_syntax
    syntax region htmlSnip matchgroup=SnipHTML start="html`" end="`" contains=@HTML

    syntax include @JSON syntax/json.vim
    unlet b:current_syntax
    syntax region jsonSnip matchgroup=SnipJSON start="json`" end="`" contains=@JSON

    syntax include @CPP syntax/cpp.vim
    unlet b:current_syntax
    syntax region cppSnip matchgroup=SnipCPP start="@begin=cpp@" end="@end=cpp@" contains=@CPP

endfunction


:help syn-include should be clearer.
